# NullPointerException on a Mariadb stored procedure call when my java server is run on our server, but not when it's run on my dev machine

Tags: java, jvm, centos, mariadb

I'm developing a server that uses Mariadb, one particular stored procedure updates an enum field if a client has successfully responded to a particular query.

When I run the server locally on my dev machine, and point it to the database on the server there are no problems, however when I compile a jar and run it on the server with the database I get a NullPointerException on the returned int of after the query executes. The error occurs at this line:

```
int rowsUpdated = callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Here's the full method call:

```
    public void updateWlanSettingsStatus(String deviceId, String status) {
        try {

            connection = database.getConnection();
            CallableStatement callableStatement = connection
                    .prepareCall("{call updateWlanSettingsStatus(?,?)}");
            callableStatement.setString(1, deviceId);
            callableStatement.setString(2, status);

            int rowsUpdated = callableStatement.executeUpdate();

            connection.close();
            log.debug("DataDAO: Rows Updated: " + rowsUpdated);
            log.debug("DataDAO: wlan settings update complete for " + deviceId);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("DataDAO An SQLException occured!", e);
            closeDbConnection(connection);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("DataDAO An Exception Occurred:", e);
            closeDbConnection(connection);

        }
```

I'm developing on Windows 8 and the server is running CentOs.
My machine is running java 1.8 and compiling to 1.7.  The server is running 1.7

This is the error I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLCallableStatement.getUpdateCount(MySQLCallableStatement.java:1471) 
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLCallableStatement.executeUpdate(MySQLCallableStatement.java:1131) 
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementProxy.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementProxy.java:61) 
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.CallableStatementJavassistProxy.executeUpdate(CallableStatementJavassistProxy.java) 
        at com.watersprint.deviceapi.data.DataDAO.updateWlanSettingsStatus(DataDAO.java:586) 
        at com.watersprint.deviceapi.server.WorkerRunnable.processResultOfMessage(WorkerRunnable.java:133) 
        at com.watersprint.deviceapi.server.WorkerRunnable.processJsonObject(WorkerRunnable.java:110) 
        at com.watersprint.deviceapi.server.WorkerRunnable.run(WorkerRunnable.java:63) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The Server Java specs:

> java version "1.7.0_75"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment
>   (rhel-2.5.4.2.el7_0-x86_64 u75-b13)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM  (build
>   24.75-b4, mixed mode)

My dev machine Java spec:

> java version "1.8.0_25"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

As I said, I'm compiling the project to java 1.7.

The code executes as expected, the database is updated as expected, all values are correct after execution even though the error occurs.

I'm am considering uninstalling Java 1.8 and reverting to 1.7. 
What am I missing here? Is reverting my machines version of Java the best thing to do? Am I missing something else?

Comment: Can you evidentiate wich is row number 61?

Comment: That's part of `java.sql.PreparedStatement` I don't have the source for that.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Wich is row number 586

Comment: I just ran this on a cloud server with the same OS and the same Java versions, it ran without any issues. So I no longer think it's a JVM issue.

Comment: This one: `int rowsUpdated = callableStatement.executeUpdate();`

Comment: You might try turning off the hikari proxy.